# Proper Model Field For One To One Database Relationships In Django

Tags: django, database, orm, foreign-key-relationship

My issue is that my app is not allowing me to update a `OneToOneField` field. Here's my explanation of what I'm trying to do.

I am building an inventory app that keeps track of instruments that have been loaned to students. There will always be a one-to-one database relationship between students and instruments. So an individual student can't ever have more than one instrument and vice versa.

I therefore created an Intrument model that looks like this:

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    instrument_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    needs_repairs   = models.BooleanField()
    inventory_id    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student         = models.OneToOneField(Student, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
```

I have created a form that allows me to update existing students, and I'm trying to use as much built-in stuff as possible so that I don't need to re-write validation code or HTML. So I'm using a `ModelForm` object and validating my input using the `is_valid()` method.

Here's an example of a POST request to update an instrument:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=xyUBhVuQZus6XmeV2DhCmpJHwIXVmdHm&instrument_type=Viola&inventory_id=abcde&student=3
```

Please note that the only field with a uniqueness constraint is `student`.

So finally, here's the problem:  when I call the `is_valid()` method it always fails with an error saying that the student has already been assigned to an instrument.

My first thought was to use the framework to add some pre-validation code that didn't error if the student pkey didn't change. This certainly seems easy enough, but it seems to be a bit hacky to me. I assumed that one-to-one relationships would "just work" like all of the other Model fields and that no special validation would be required.

But then I read the API docs for the `OneToOneField` class and it doesn't seem to address one-to-one *database* relationships - it seems to address *one-to-one OO relationships*. So I may be using the wrong Model field type all together. And since this is such a simple app, I'm not performing a ton of OO modeling - I'm just worried about proper data modeling :-)

So am I using the wrong field, or is the "proper" way to fix this to add pre-validation code to my Student model?

**Updates From Comments**

Here's the closest thing that I have to a stack trace:

```
>>> data = {'instrument_type': 'Viola', 'inventory_id': 'abcde', 'student': 3, 'repairer': 1}
>>> form = InstrumentForm(data)
>>> form.is_bound
True
>>> form.is_valid()
False
>>> form.errors
{'student': [u'Instrument with this Student already exists.']}
```

I use a single view method to display Instrument detail and update a single Instrument. Here's that:

```
def instrument_detail(request, instrument_id):

    try:
        instrument = Instrument.objects.get(pk=instrument_id)
    except Instrument.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    # Default if not a POST
    form = InstrumentForm(instance=instrument)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstrumentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('instruments.views.instruments_index'))

    # otherwise...

    t = loader.get_template('instruments/details.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'instrument': instrument,
        'form': form,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: Can you please include your error stack trace???

Comment: *Am I using the wrong field?* No. O2O is indeed a database-level relation (foreign key with a unique constraint). *Is the "proper" way to fix this to add pre-validation code to my Student model?* No. I think there's just a bug in your code somewhere. You'll need to post the stacktrace and the view code handling the form if you want help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the instance when instantiating the form on POST.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InstrumentForm(request.POST, instance=instrument)
```